# Selecting multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying and searching for a while now about how to go around achieving my goal.

**What I've got:**

```
(?<={).*?(?=})
```

This kind of works but doesn't recursively check for matches.

**What I need to achieve:**

Example:

```
ACCOUNT{username:test}{password:pass}{email:demo@example.com}
```

What I need to get is all the text inside the { and }.

**This code is being used in:**

```
Regex r = new Regex("(?<={).*?(?=})");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(data);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    dataCont.addData(m.Value.Substring(0, m.Value.IndexOf(':')), 
                     m.Value.Substring(m.Value.IndexOf(':') + 1));
}
```

So that I'll end up with 'username:test', 'password:pass' and so on.

(At the moment I'm getting only 1 match.)

**Edit:** The code is WORKING, people can use it for reference.

Comment: I don't know much of Regex, but check if iterative matching is allowed

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting `Substring` from `data` instead of `m.Value`.

Change

```
dataCont.addData(
        m.Value.Substring(0, data.IndexOf(':')), 
        m.Value.Substring(data.IndexOf(':')+1));
```

to

```
dataCont.addData(
        m.Value.Substring(0, m.Value.IndexOf(':')), 
        m.Value.Substring(m.Value.IndexOf(':')+1));
```

Moreover, instead of getting substring you can use the `Split` method of string -

```
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    string[] keyValue = m.Value.Split(':');
    dataCont.addData(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```

Comment: Although that wasn't the problem, that was a problem :)

Comment: I wasn't saying that this was the answer, this is helped me fix ANOTHER problem, which I completely missed. The original problem still remains.

Comment: After this edit although i am getting three matches for your sample input. I suspect issue must be in your method `addData`. Can you check with debugger count value of mc?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not sure what I've changed in the last few minutes but it's definitely working now. I'm guessing it wasn't compiling for some odd reason and running the last compiled version.

Comment: Hmmm.. On a sidenote you can get away with substring part by using split on the matched string. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply:

```
\{(?<data>.*?)\}
```

Or, to separate out the keys and values:

```
\{(?<key>.*?):(?<value>.*?)\}
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach( Match m in matches )
{
    var key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
    var value = m.Groups["value"].Value;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your example would be used? <data>, <key> and <value> are the confusing parts. Am I supposed to enter values there? If so then this isn't what I'm looking for. The keys will be different as the method they're in is being used for a lot of different things.

Comment: *key* and *value* are the names of the regex groups. When using this approach, you need to iterate over the captures returned by the regex, like this:  var input = @"ACCOUNT{username:test}{password:pass}{email:demo@example.com}";
 var pattern = @"\{(?<key>.*?):(?<value>.*?)\}";
 var regex = new Regex(pattern);
 foreach (Match capture in regex.Matches(input))
 {
  Console.Out.WriteLine(capture.Value);
 }

Output is:
{username:test}
{password:pass}
{email:demo@example.com}

I wrote a comment because this is a good and correct answer.

Comment: The syntax (?<name>...) is simply a way to name each capture group, so instead of having to access each group by index, you can access it by name. Also, separating out the data in the regex looks fancier than splitting the string manually!

Comment: The idea was not to have the { }'s, but this would have been the answer if someone did want them. I tried to up vote it as useful but I needed 15 rep.

Comment: The regex I wrote will give you the data without the {}, if that's what you meant.